# How to disable a user from re-filling the same form?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way a user can be disabled from re-filling same form? Or link to open that form can be disabled for second use?

Comment: I think it would be better to do it using a Server Side Language, like ASP or PHP. Connecting to the Database and check if the user ad already filled in the form

Comment: use database,sessions,cookies all to gether

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the other persons browser. Javascript is just to make the users experience of your web site better. Also do not trust it and do all checking on your server

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, depending on the UI flow.

If you're simply interested in preventing accidental duplicate submissions of data, follow the [**PRD (Post Redirect Get)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?PHP session_start();?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["form_viewd"]) and $_SESSION["form_viewd"] == "yes"): ?>
    <span>you filled this form</span>
<?php else: $_SESSION["form_viewd"] = "yes"; ?>
    <form>
    </form>
<?php endif; sesseion_destroy(); ?>
```